# Make sticky work only on desktop version

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, sticky

I've got this sticky code working on one of my divs. I was wondering if it was possible to only work on desktops... I don't want it to be sticky on mobiles or tablets.

```
var $window = $(window),
   $stickyEl = $('#single_text'),
   elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;

$window.scroll(function() {
    $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
});
```

Comment: @Blazemonger I don't think modernizr tells you if a site is mobile/tablet or not.

Comment: No, there is no 100% reliable way to tell if you're using a smartphone/tablet or not, partly because the definition is getting blurred -- which would you consider the Microsoft Surface to be? Instead, you need to consider which *features* are important (touchscreen, small screen, Adobe Flash, etc.) and detect those instead. Your question is unanswerable because you haven't defined what you consider a mobile/tablet device to be.

Answer (score 0):

The logic itself is simple, but accurate detection of mobile/tablet devices is sort of complicated to do these days, given all of the devices, screen sizes, user agents, etc.

Basically, you need to test for mobile/tablet or not, set that to a variable (true/false), then execute your JavaScript if it's not mobile.

```
var isMobile = false;
if(mobileDetection == true) { // mobileDetection is the missing piece
    isMobile = true;
}

if(!isMobile) {
    // execute desktop-only JS
}
```

I'd suggest reading over these materials:

- [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser)
- [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)
- http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/